# Write two matrices in beamer in easier manner

Tags: beamer

How to write this two type of matrix in beamer in a most easier manner?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try with the package `nicematrix`. Easy to learn and with lots of examples in the manual.

[image: xxx]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}    
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Two matrices}

    $ \mathbf{y}_i =
                    \begin{pNiceMatrix}
                        x_{i1}  \\
                        \vdots  \\
                        x_{it}  \\
                        \vdots  \\
                        x_{iT} 
                    \end{pNiceMatrix}_{T\,x\,1} 
\hfill \mathbf{X}_i =
                    \begin{pNiceMatrix}
                        x_{i,1,1}   & x_{i,1,2} & x_{i,1,j}     & \cdots & x_{i,1,K}   \\
                        \vdots      & \vdots    &    \vdots     &        & \vdots      \\
                        x_{i,t,1}   & x_{i,t,2} & x_{i,t,j}     & \cdots & x_{i,1,K}   \\
                        \vdots      & \vdots    &    \vdots     &        & \vdots      \\
                        x_{i,T,1}   & x_{i,T,2} & x_{i,T,j}     & \cdots &  x_{i,T,K}
                    \end{pNiceMatrix}_{T\,x\,K} $
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good :-)...

Answer (score 0):

This simple matrix can be writen by `pmatrix` defined in the `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Two matrices}
    \[
\mathbf{y}_i = \begin{pmatrix}
                        x_{i1}  \\
                        \vdots  \\
                        x_{it}  \\
                        \vdots  \\
                        x_{iT}
               \end{pmatrix}_{T\times 1}
\qquad\mathbf{X}_i =
                    \begin{pmatrix}
                        x_{i,1,1}   & x_{i,1,2} & x_{i,1,j}     & \cdots & x_{i,1,K}   \\
                        \vdots      & \vdots    &    \vdots     &        & \vdots      \\
                        x_{i,t,1}   & x_{i,t,2} & x_{i,t,j}     & \cdots & x_{i,1,K}   \\
                        \vdots      & \vdots    &    \vdots     &        & \vdots      \\
                        x_{i,T,1}   & x_{i,T,2} & x_{i,T,j}     & \cdots &  x_{i,T,K}
                    \end{pmatrix}_{T\times K} 
    \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For result below is needed only one compilation.

[image]